# How is this mean scale score range calculated?

Tags: t-test, range

I have the attached report for a standardized test (data in the report is simulated).  I'm wondering how the column Mean Scale Score Range is calculated.  Do the lines indicate the limits of 95% of the scores?  If so, when they recommend looking at whether the lines overlap when comparing years, is this equivalent to a t-test with an alpha of .05?

This report is from [here](https://www.canadiantestcentre.com/pdfs/CAT_DTAR.pdf)
[image: mean scale score range]

Comment: This may be useful: https://www.cscu.cornell.edu/news/statnews/stnews73.pdf

Comment: It doesn't look like a very competently put together report. It's not clear, but one can only presume that those are supposed to be 95% confidence intervals. And while it is true that non-overlapping confidence intervals for a specific pair of years indicates a significant difference, it is not true that overlapping confidence intervals necessarily indicates that the difference is not statistically significant.

Comment: @Denziloe I'm checking with the test issuer to confirm whether that is indeed the 95% CI.

Comment: The publisher of the test confirmed that the lines indicate the 95% CI